# Why is dummy '0' row created after pd.read_csv()?

Tags: python, pandas

Why there is an additional row named '0' after read_csv?

In the following code, I saved df1 to csv file and read it back. However, there is an additional row named '0'. How can I avoid it?

```
d1 = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}
df1=pd.Series(d1)
print('\ndf1:'); print(df1)

> df1:
> a    1
> b    2
> c    3
> dtype: int64

df1.to_csv("df1.csv")
df1=pd.read_csv("df1.csv",  index_col=0, header=None)
print('\ndf1:'); print(df1)

> df1:
>   1
> 0    <<<<---- ????
> a  1
> b  2
> c  3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to avoid it is to create a DataFrame (as your variable name suggests) instead of a Series (which you have atm).

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}
df1 = pd.Series(d1).to_frame()    # Use to_frame() here
df1.to_csv("df1.csv")
df1 = pd.read_csv("df1.csv", index_col=0)
```

print(df1) gives:

```
   0
a  1
b  2
c  3
```

---

**Another solution** would be to actually specify names when you import.
In case you opt for this solution I would however rename the df1 to s1 when you create a series for readability.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("df1.csv", names=['index','values'], index_col='index')
```

And you get:

```
       values
index        
a           1
b           2
c           3
```

**Full example:**

```
d1 = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}
s1 = pd.Series(d1)
print('s1:\n{}\n'.format(s1))

s1.to_csv("df1.csv")
df1 = pd.read_csv("df1.csv", names=['index','values'], index_col='index')
print('df1:\n{}\n'.format(df1))
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not a dummy row - that is the name of your indexing Column.

You can check it by running:

```
> df.index.name
0
```

You can change it by setting it too:

```
> df.index.name = "my_index"

          1
my_index   
a         1
b         2
c         3
```